# How to remove .com from an url in python?

Tags: python, urlparse

I want to remove the domain in an url 
For e.g. User entered www.google.com 
But I only need www.google

How to do this in python?
Thanks

Comment: What if the user entered `www.google.com.au` or `www.google.co.uk`?

Comment: @Aryan, Please edit your question with more details as it seems too abroad, narrow down to your requirements!

Comment: I think it's worth adding that when you set out to manipulate urls, figuring out what the actual requirements are in all possible cases is usually much harder than writing the code.

Comment: @mhawke The question says remove domain name, so answer still would be `www.google`. In any case, to avoid complexity, we can look for dots starting from the left and stop at second one.

Comment: @Learner: yes, but the question title asks only how to remove `.com`. `.com` is the top level domain... but `google.com` can also be considered the domain, so that would leave just `www`, which I suppose is not what is intended. The question needs clarification.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very general question. But the narrowest answer would be as follows (assuming `url` holds the URL in question):

```
if url.endswith(".com"):
    url = url[:-4]
```

If you want to remove the last period and everything to the right of it the code would be a little more complicated:

```
pos = url.rfind('.') # find rightmost dot
if pos >= 0:         # found one
    url = url[:pos]
```

Comment: `url.rsplit('.', 1)[0]` will split on the rightmost dot and return the first item

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: or `url.rpartition('.')[0]`.

Comment: As @SteveJessop points out, the eTLD (effective top-level domain) might be made up of multiple components. For example, `.co.uk` is the UK equivalent of the originally American and now global `.com` domain.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this without having the problem of dealing with domain name, you can look for the dots from left hand side and stop at the second dot.

```
t = 'www.google.com'
a = t.split('.')[1]
pos = t.find(a)
t = t[:pos+len(a)]

>>> 'www.google'
```

Comment: Does not work with `meta.codereview.stackexchange.com`. No irony intended.

Comment: This fails on anything with more than one `.` in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove 4 characters at the end, slice it

```
url = 'www.google.com'
cut_url = str[:-4]
# output : 'www.google'
```

---

*More advanced answer*

If you have a list of all the possible domains `domains`:

```
domains = ['com', 'uk', 'fr', 'net', 'co', 'nz']  # and so on...
while True:
    domain = url.split('.')[-1]
    if domain in domains:
        url = '.'.join(url.split('.')[:-1])
    else:
        break
```

Or if, for example, you have a domains list where `.co` and `.uk` are not separated:

```
domains = ['.com', '.co.uk', '.fr', '.net', '.co.nz']  # and so on...
for domain in domains:
    if url.endswith(domain):
        cut_url = url[:-len(domain)]
        break
else:  # there is no indentation mistake here.
       # else after for will be executed if for did not break
    print('no known domain found')
```

Comment: What about `www.mysite.io` or `www.mysite.om`? .. etc

Comment: Then maybe `'.'join(mystr.split('.')[:-1])`. But what about `.co.uk`? The problem is under-specified, since the questioner says "remove the domain", whereas `.com` and `google.com` and `www.google.com` are all domains of different sorts. A complete solution might require using the Mozilla Public Suffix List, depending on the actual problem.

Comment: Was going to edit to include these cases, but I first wanted to provide a simple answer for OP's question as it was asked

Comment: `str` is really bad name for variable

Comment: @SteveJessop would you rather add all the possible domain name manually, or try to use how the url is wirtten to get the domain name out of it ?

Comment: @HolyDanna: depends on the problem. The issue is that in practice it's hardly ever meaningful to remove just the TLD, what matters is the eTLD. For real problems I've used the PSL, which means *someone else* has added all the possible domain names manually. Best of both worlds, it's accurate but I don't have to maintain it.

Answer (score -1):

What you need here is `rstrip` function.

Try this code:

```
url = 'www.google.com'
url2 = 'www.google'

new_url = url.rstrip('.com')
print (new_url)

new_url2 = url2.rstrip('.com')
print (new_url2)
```

`rstrip` will only strip if the string is present, in this case ".com". If not, it will just leave it. `rstrip` is for stripping 'right-most' matched string and `lstrip` is the opposite of this. Check these [docs](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rstrip.html).
Also check [strip](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/strip.html) and [lstrip](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/lstrip.html) functions.

## UPDATE

As @SteveJessop pointed out that the above example **is NOT the right solution** so i'm submitting another solution, though it's related to another answer here, it does check first if the string ends with a '.com'.

```
url = 'www.foo.com'
if url.endswith('.com'):
    url = url[:-4]
    print (url)
```

Comment: Well, except that `'www.foo.com'.rstrip('.com')` is `www.f`

Comment: In case readers are having trouble working out *why* this is so, the argument to `rsrtrip` specifies a _set_ of characters, any and all of which will be removed from the right-hand end of the string.

Comment: @SteveJessop , thanks for pointing it out :) appreciate that! What do you think about the updated solution? even though it's related to another user's answer, i believe this should help the asker